# Could not append a csv file with dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to coding and learning python. I have been trying to create a program which asks user information about a part and then appends it to a file. Once it appends the file, I should be able to see the information in the file if i open it. However, the program is not saving the information on file. I might be doing a silly mistake but I have not been able to figure out as I am totally new to coding.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

colnames = ['name', 'numid', 'length', 'height']
parts_info = pd.read_csv('part.info', sep ='\t', header = None, names = colnames, index_col = 'name')

New_parts = {}

class Part:
    name = ""
    numid = 0
    height = 0
    length = 0

    def display(self):
        print ''
        print 'Part Information:'
        print parts_info

    def get(self):
        self.name = raw_input('Enter Part Name: ')
        self.numid = int(raw_input('Enter NumId: '))
        self.height = float(raw_input('Enter Height (in feet): '))
        self.length = int(raw_input('Enter Length: '))

    def new_part(self):
        New_parts[self.name] = {'numid':self.numid, 'height':self.height, 'length':self.length}

    def save(self):
        with open('part.info','a') as f:
            parts_info.to_csv(f, header = False)
        f.close()

onePart = None

if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'READ':
    onePart = Part()
else:
    onePart = Part()
    onePart.get()
    onePart.new_part()
    onePart.save()

New_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(New_parts,orient='index')
New_df.index.name = 'name'

parts_info = parts_info.append(New_df)
onePart.display()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code corrections and Commentary

There are a couple things:

1. You do not need to define the column names, when using [`pd.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), they will be inferred from the `csv` based on the [default `header=` argument](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=header). Also [`index_col=`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=index_col) should be an `int`.  You can read in with

   ```
   parts_info = pd.read_csv('part.info', sep ='\t', index_col=0)
   ```
2. When `.save()` is called no data has been appended to the DataFrame yet.  Put some `print` statements in so you can see the flow, like

   ```
   def save(self):
       print 'saving', parts_info
       with open('part.info','a') as f:
           parts_info.to_csv(f, header = False)
   ```

   or

   ```
   print 'make new part'
   onePart = Part()
   print 'get new part info'
   onePart.get()
   print 'add to log'
   onePart.new_part()
   print 'save it to csv'
   onePart.save()
   ```

   **You need to restructure your code so things happen in the order you want them to.**
3. When you use

   ```
   with open('/path/to/file', 'a') as f:
   ```

   you do not need

   ```
   f.close()
   ```

   See the [best practice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) behind the `with` statement.